# Issues with re-arranging this formula

Tags: arithmetic

I am needing to put the formula $(\sqrt5+\sqrt7)(\sqrt5-\sqrt7)$ into the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$

Although it looks fairly simple, I do not know where to start with this. Please could someone explain the methodology to me so that I can learn to get to the correct answer ? This would be very much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\sqrt5+\sqrt7)(\sqrt5-\sqrt7)=5-7=-2=-2+0\cdot\sqrt \pi$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$(\sqrt5+\sqrt7)(\sqrt5-\sqrt7) = 5-7 = -2$

which you can also write as $-2 + 1\sqrt{0}$

Comment: Thankyou , I was able to get to the solution of -2, but didn not think it would be as simple as adding $1\sqrt0$

Comment: Why "$\;1\sqrt0\;$",  and not $\;0\cdot\sqrt{\text{whatever non-negative}}\;$ ? It looks odd...but it is correct, of course.

Comment: "can be written" does not imply a single solution @DonAntonio

Comment: @adjan Oh, thank you: I knew that...

Comment: @DonAntonio what a useless comment.

Comment: @adjan I'm glad to see you accept that of your past comment. Good.

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant your comment, stop being sarcastic. Since the OP's question does not have any constraints there are infinitely many solutions. You don't have to play the smart guy by stating the obvious

Comment: @adjan You seem to be missing the point: I tell you that $\;1\sqrt0\;$ looks "funny", as many people would usually write $\;0\cdot\sqrt1\;$ or whatever inside the root...and of course your solution is fine as it is *the same*!  Yet you seem to feel aggravated and respond me a triviality that any 2nd degree children school knows. Come on, stop being over sensitive and learn to read **and understand** what is being said to you .in good spirit.